# How to return results for a query using pivot or something similar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, pivot

I need to write a select to produce the following:

```
   r_country | s_country |     s_name  |  r_name | msg    |   date
     ca        au            bill       bob      'hi'       2/12/2010
```

Here is my data:

```
tableA

EmployeeName   |  EmployeeID  | country
bill              1                au
bob               2                ca


tableB

Sender       |  Reciever  |  Msg | date
bill               bob       'hi'   12/12/2010
```

earlier i tried to do a join, but i think that this will only return data for the user whose name i join on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join twice.

```
SELECT
  receiver.country    AS r_country,
  sender.country      AS s_country,
  data.Sender         AS s_name,
  data.Receiver       AS r_name,
  data.msg            AS msg,
  data.date           AS date
FROM
  TableB              AS data
LEFT JOIN
  TableA              AS sender
    ON sender.EmployeeName = data.Sender
LEFT JOIN
  TableA              AS receiver
    ON receiver.EmployeeName = data.Receiver
```

Also note, however, that your data (fact) tables should not hold the NAME in them.  You should be using the UniqueID of the entity, a field that is independent of the entity attributes (such as name, address, etc)